# Extract subvector in constant time

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, time-complexity

I have a `std::vector<int>` and I want to throw away the x first and y last elements. Just copying the elements is not an option, since this is `O(n)`.
Is there something like `vector.begin()+=x` to let  the vector just start later and end earlier?
I also tried

```
items = std::vector<int> (&items[x+1],&items[0]+items.size()-y);
```

where items is my vector, but this gave me `bad_alloc`

Comment: Maybe you should state what the high-level problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: What will you do with extracted vector? May writing a wrapper for `begin` and `end` iterator be a solution? This is not a real `vector`, though, it will allow you to iterate over it and get access to random element. It is also possible to write `push_back` and `push_front` methods, which will replace the existing elements, but in this case you should  also store original `vector`. And, as another solution, you might take a look at the idea of persistent collections.

Comment: I'm implementing algorithms to calculate lower bounds for the bin-packing problem. In a first step I reduce the problem by throwing away all items that are alone or as a pair in a bin in an optimal solution. Since my vector is sorted, those elements are the last and first elements. Edit: My algorithms are `O(n)` and I don't want to blow it up to `O(n^2)`

Comment: Why would you need to "blow it up to `O(n^2)`" to alter your iteration range? o.O

Comment: Well, I confused two things there. It wouldn't do harm to the time-complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ standard algorithms work on *ranges*, not on actual containers, so you don't need to extract anything: you just need to adjust the iterator range you're working with.

```
void foo(const std::vector<T>& vec, const size_t start, const size_t end)
{
    assert(vec.size() >= end-start);
    auto it1 = vec.begin() + start;
    auto it2 = vec.begin() + end;

    std::whatever(it1, it2);
}
```

I don't see why it needs to be any more complicated than that.

#### ([trivial live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c035b6dbe662a90))

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, trying your code suggestion, I get  `error: it1 doesn't name a type`.

Comment: @Ricardo: Still stuck on C++03? You'll have to write `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` instead of `auto`, then. (remove `const` and set `T` as appropriate)

Comment: Well it works now.  And I also learned how to enable C++11. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a range of values, you can represent that as a pair of iterators from first to last element of the range. These can be acquired in constant time.

Edit: According to the description in the comments, this seems like the most sensible solution. If your functions expect a vector reference, then you'll need to refactor a bit.

Other solutions:

If you don't need the original vector, and therefore can modify it, and the order of elements is not relevant, you can swap the first `x` elements with the `n-x-y...n-y` elements and then remove the last `x+y` elements. This can be done in `O(x+y)` time.

If appropriate, you could choose to use `std::list` for which what you're asking can be done in constant time if you have iterators to the first and last node of the sublist. This also requires that you can modify the original list but the order of elements won't change.

If those are not options, then you need to copy and are stuck with `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct: usually iterators will do.

Nevertheless, you can also write a vector view. Here is a sketch:

```
template<typename T>
struct vector_view
{
    vector_view(std::vector<T> const& v, size_t ind_begin, size_t ind_end)
        : _v(v)
        , _size(/* size of range */)
        , _ind_begin(ind_begin) {}

    auto size() const { return _size; }

    auto const& operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        //possibly check for input outside range
        return _v[ i + _ind_begin ];
    }

    //conversion of view to std::vector
    operator std::vector<T>() const
    {
        std::vector<T> ret(_size);
        //fill it
        return ret;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> const& _v;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _ind_begin;
}
```

Expose further methods as required (some iterator stuff might be appropriate when you want to use that with the standard library algorithms).

Further, take care on the validity of the const reference `std::vector<T> const& v;` -- if that could be an issue, one should better work with shared-pointers.

One can also think of more general approaches here, for example, use strides or similar things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sure. This is why I wrote *sketch* ... which roughly means: "I was too lazy to do it correctly, figure it out for yourself." ... but for explicit suggestions I'll correct it of course :-)